# Printing Unicode characters using write(2) in c

Tags: c, unicode, wchar-t

I'm working on a small piece of code that prints characters to the screen, and must support all of Unicode contained in a `wchar_t`, and i'm limited to only `write(2)`. I managed to print an emoji using :

```
write(1, "\U0001f921", 6);
```

So `\U` seem to be the way to go. However, i can't get to convert the `wchar_t` into the proper escape sequence, ie converting `wchar_t c = L'';` into `\U0001f921`

Can i even do that in C ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You probably want UTF-8

Comment: Yeah, maybe. How would i go about converting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm working on a small piece of code that prints characters to the
>   screen, and must support all of Unicode contained in a wchar_t, and
>   i'm limited to only write(2).

That's a problematic combination of requirements.  In particular, `wchar_t` character representation may very well not play nicely with using `write()` for output.

More generally, there are multiple issues here, among them:

1. The members of the source and execution character sets.
2. How to represent extended characters of the execution character set in your source (via the source character set).
3. How to present extended characters of the execution character set to the output device of your choice, so that device handles them as desired.

Note well that that C specifies only a fairly small set of characters that *must* be present in the execution character set.  Additional, "extended", characters *may* be present in it, and your emoji would fall into this category.  Dealing with extended characters via the standard C interfaces is a bit mushy, as the standard affords implementations a great deal freedom in how they do things there.

> So `\U` seem to be the way to go.

The `\U` introduces a "*universal character name*".  It is important to understand that these sequences are converted to members of the execution character set during compilation.

> However, i can't get to convert the
>   wchar_t into the proper escape sequence, ie converting `wchar_t c =
>   L'';` into `\U0001f921`

It is not safe to assume that '' can be represented directly in the source character set, so as to use it literally in your source code.  That depends on your C implementation.  A universal character name is safer.  Furthermore, if you want a wide character constant then you can try `L'\U0001f921'`, but there's a good chance that `wchar_t` cannot represent that character.  In particular, many implementations have 16-bit `wchar_t`, and those are unlikely to be able to support your character as a (single) `wchar_t`.

You may have better luck with a wide string literal: `L"\U0001f921"`, but this is useful to you primarily if you are working with the wide-character-specific functions, which will perform appropriate encoding conversions for you.  `write()` will not perform such conversions, so whether it produces the desired result will depend on the configuration of your runtime environment.  I judge your original approach, with an ordinary string literal, to be more likely to work.

If you wish, and if you can use C2011 features, then you can also express a (regular) string literal that is defined to be encoded in UTF-8, regardless of what the actual execution character set is.  The form for that would be `u8"\U0001f921"`.  Again, though, producing your desired result this way depends on your environment.  UTF-8 literals are better suited to interacting with interfaces that are specifically defined to use UTF-8.

> Can i even do that in C ?

It is not safe to assume that your emoji character can be represented by a single object of type `wchar_t`.  There may be C implementations that support it, but I think they are uncommon.

One final note: this code ...

```
write(1, "\U0001f921", 6);
```

... almost certainly exhibits undefined behavior as a result of overrunning the bounds of the `char` array you are presenting to `write()`.  I don't see any plausible scenario in which it is longer than 5 characters, but you write 6, overrunning by at least 1.  If the internal representation is UTF-8, then that array will have length 4 -- three bytes encoding the character, and one for the string terminator.

You should measure the length to find out how many bytes to write, for example:

```
const char *emoji = "\U0001f921";
write(1, emoji, strlen(emoji));
```

Comment: All right, i think i got a good base to work on. Thanks a lot for the writeup. I should have added that i target OSX, and compatibility with other systems is not really something i care about in my case. 
So i will experiment with you advices, and try to implement theses freaking unicodes character...

Comment: So i checked, and the input i get isn't in the form of a \Uxxxxx as i thought i would be. I get L"String ....", so i really need to convert from the number to the correct charcater, don't i ?

Comment: @Rogue, I'm uncertain what you are asking.  The representation of a character in computer memory *is* a number or a sequence of them.  Perhaps you are being confused by how a debugger is presenting memory to you.  Anyway, it is conceivable that you will need to convert between different (numeric) representations of your characters, but you haven't given me any basis to say anything specific about that.

Comment: Well, to smplify, my function takes an imput in the form of a single wchar_t, which is called like this: ````print_unicode(L'é');````, but that mean i can't use my handy dandy \Uxxxx technique because i only get the xxxx part, not the full \Uxxxx. Not sure this makes sense ...

Comment: @Rogue, refer to the part of my answer where I observe that a single `wchar_t` may not even be able to represent your particular character.  It sounds very much like that's what you've run into.  There is no workaround for that short of redesigning your function signatures.

Comment: I ended up solving this by converting the codepoints to the proper UTF-8 bytes. As i only target OSX i will keep using wchar_t which, according to my testing fits well. Thanks for you detailed input !